# Why is Click binding undefined when using this declared in a returned RequireJS function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I am using Require JS as illustrated in the code below. However, I cannot get the click binding to work if I declared this within the returned function
If I place this outside of the function, the code works.

This does not work:

```
    return function viewModelA() {

        var self = this;

        self.SelectedTableRow = function(selectedRowData){
             // Do something with return value
        };
}
```

This works:

```
    var self = this;

    return function viewModelA() {

        self.SelectedTableRow = function(selectedRowData){
             // Do something with return value
        };
}
```

*Complete code:*

```
define(function(require){

    var $  = require ('jquery');
    var ko = require ('knockout');
    var viewModelB = require ('ViewModelB/ViewModelB');

    var self = this;
    return function viewModelA() {

        var self = this;

        self.member = {};
        self.member.countries = ko.observableArray();

        $.getJSON('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all', function(data) {
            self.member.countries(data);
        });

        self.SelectedTableRow = function(selectedRowData){
             // Do something with return value
        };

        return{
           member: self.member
        }
    }
});
```

*Abbreviated HTML:*

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: member.countries">
    <tr data-bind="click: SelectedTableRow, clickBubble: false">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside/outside viewModelA are different based on how the function is invoked. You are returning viewModelA which is being invoke by some one else.

Try this

```
return function viewModelA() {
    var self = this;    
    self.SelectedTableRow = function(selectedRowData){
        // Do something with return value
    };
}.bind(this)
```

Comment: Thanks my friend: I also discovered that I was instantiating a new instance of the function which means I was binding a different instance. So instead of `var vma = new viewModelA();` I am simply doing: `ko.applyBindings(viewModelA, document.getElementById('section-a'));` This works with or without the `bind(this)`.